# Why is the learning rate sometimes called alpha?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, terminology

While viewing multiple codes I encountered that some different people are referring to the learning rate as "alpha". Where are the roots of it? Is it common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update rule for a parameter/weight in a gradient decent algorithm is

[image]

i.e we take a small value (multiple) of the gradient and adjust the current value of parameters. This quantity of gradient we are taking is determined by the alpha. The higher the alpha the larger portion of the current gradient is consider and smaller the alpha the smaller is the considered gradient.

This alpha is called the learning rate because the higher the alpha the faster we are moving and lower the alpha the slower the movement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the exact historical origins, but in general it is very common to use the greek alphabet as shorthand in maths and computer science. Alpha is just the symbol α - the first letter of the Greek alphabet.